# Error While Launching AVD in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator

Please help I am getting the following error While launching AVD

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 256MB
Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 512M
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB

#### WARNING: unable to configure any DNS servers, name resolution will not work

Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '25.1.7'
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 256MB
Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 512M
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB

#### WARNING: unable to configure any DNS servers, name resolution will not work

Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '25.1.7'
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPAj5.png)

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM did you configure HAXM for when it installed?  If you installed HAXM to use 512M, then your AVD isn't going to be able to use more than that.

I'd try installing it again: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x